A $G$-action on $X\times Y$ induces actions on $X$ and $Y$?
It's easily seen that the converse is true (simply define $g(x, y) := (gx, gy)$). However, while analyzing the original statement, I got stuck and soon realised that there is no reason for that to be true. In particular, there's nothing ensuring that the projections are "well-behaved" with the action: The first coordinate of $g\cdot(x, y)$ needn't solely depend on just $x$.
Thus, I am looking for examples of actions which exhibit this. Unfortunately, the only ones that I know of, namely the action of $\mathbb K^*$ on $\mathbb K^n$ ($\mathbb K = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$), or the action of $\mathbb Z^n$ on $\mathbb R^n$ (to obtain the $n$-torus), don't suffice. Do you know any?

Edit:
Thanks to @Numeral's comment, my question needs to be refined. The question is:

Suppose $G$ acts on $X\times Y\ne\emptyset$. Fixing a $y_0\in Y$, we can define $G\times X\to G\times (X\times Y)\to X\times Y\to X$. Does this define an action? Prove or give a counterexample.


Summary of answers:
We have found three kinds of (negative) answers to this:

Thanks to @ajotaxte and @dialegou, there's a simple example: Let $\mathbb Z_2$ act on $X\times X$ by "swapping the entries".

@Numeral's answer gives a much stronger statement (thus accepting it), hinging on the fact that certain groups can't act on certain sets.

@NaïmFavier and @krm2233's (distinct) answers involve (a subgroup of) $\mathbb S^1$ (the group of rotations) acting on (a subset of) $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.
A possible reasoning is as follows: If $\mathbb S^1$ indeed induced an action on $\mathbb R$, then the "orbits" would be closed intervals centered at $0$ (of length more than $2|y_0|$), which violates their disjointness.



What about $g(x,y)=(y,x)$?

@ajotatxe That's not a group action. $e$ doesn't preserve elements.

$G$ has a trivial action on any set. Presumably you would want to discount this case?

If $X=Y$ then the group generated by the ajotaxe's $g$ is just ${e,g}$ and this example should work.

Can you specify more precisely the "this" you're looking for? Are you looking for a group $G$ that acts on all of $X\times Y$, $X$, and $Y$? Are you looking for a group action $G$ on $X\times Y$ that somehow induces group actions on $X$ and $Y$?

I think you have lost some perspective of what actions are somewhere. You definitely know some other actions of groups on sets! Try thinking about when $G$ is a subgroup of the permutation group of $X \times Y$ (this is also the state of mind you should be in to understand ajotatxe's comment).

I don't get the role of $y_0$ in the edit, as you don't use it therein.

@Kan't it is used to define the (candidate) action: send $(g, x)$ to the first component of $g(x, y_0)$.

If you permit the trivial action of $G$, then $G$ will act on all sets so the statement is true.
If you do not count the trivial action, then the statement is false.
Consider $X=\{0,1\}$ and $Y=\{0,1,2\}$. The cyclic group $C_3$ acts on $Y$ and by extension on $X\times Y$ as $\sigma(x,y)=(x,\sigma y)$. However, $C_3$ has no non-trivial action on $X$.

Why should the trivial action not be an action?

It seems you are answering the question "if there exists an action of $G$ on $X \times Y$, must there exist an action of $G$ on $X$?" - but I don't think that's what OP is asking!

@azimut I can think of no reason to discount it.

@IzaakvanDongen Ah, I had missed the edit. Thank you.

@IzaakvanDongen But that doesn't matter! Numeral's answer is stronger.

@Atom well - "if you permit the trivial action of $G$, ... the statement is true" is not an answer to your question, and might lead to some confusion left the way it is, since if taken as an answer to your question, it is incorrect. That's why I left my comment.

Answering the edit: no, this isn't necessarily an action. For example, take the action of $G = \mathbb{Z}_4$ on $X \times Y = 2 \times 2$ that cyclically permutes the elements "clockwise"; then, writing $\varphi : G \times X \to X$ for your proposed action, we have $\varphi(2, x) = 1 - x$ but $\varphi(1, \varphi(1, x)) = \varphi(1, x) = x$ for appropriate choices of $x$ and $y_0$.

I think it should be $\varphi(1, x)$ is either constantly $0$ (if $y_0 = 0$), or constantly $1$ (if $y_0 = 1$).

You're right, I had a specific $x$ in mind.

The circle $S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=1\} \cong \mathrm{SO}_2(\mathbb R)$ acts on $\mathbb C = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ (via the inclusion of $S^1$ into $\mathbb C^\times$ which acts by scalar multiplication).
Now the orbits of this action are of course the circles centred at the origin (including the "degenerate" case of the circle of radius $0$) and these orbits are parameterised by their radius. It follows that the action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb R^2$ does not induce an action on any line of the form $\mathbb R_{y_0}\!\!:=\mathbb R\times \{y_0\}$. Indeed if this were the case then the line would have to be $S^1$-stable, and hence a union of $S^1$-orbits. But for a fixed $y_0\in \mathbb R$ an orbit of radius $r$ of the $S^1$ action intersects $\mathbb R_{y_0}$ in

the empty set if the orbit has radius $r<|y_0|$;
exactly one point if the orbit has radius $r=|y_0|$;
exactly two points if the orbit has radius $r>|y_0|$.

In particular, $\mathbb R_{y_0}$ intersects an $S^1$-orbit in at most finitely many points, and since all nondegenerate orbits of $S^1$ are uncountable it follows that $\mathbb R_{y_0}$ cannot be a union of orbits.

Nice response! But I don't think this answers the original post. While I agree that the action can't be restricted to $\mathbb R\times{y_0}$ for the reasons you specify, I don't think it's enough to imply the nonexistence of $G$'s action on $\mathbb R$ as I require? Note that in the middle arrow, I don't require that $g\cdot (x, y_0)$'s second coordinate be $y_0$.
